# How to force the JVM to clear all WeakReferences / keys of a WeakHashMap

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm, weak-references

Is there a way to force the jvm that it should clear all `WeakReferences` (or all keys of a `WeakHashMap`) if they aren't referenced by regular references anymore?

Triggering a garbage collection will not work, the weak references remain alive.
(I read that weak references will only be cleared if the memory is low).

Comment: Why do you want to do it? There might be other ways of achieving your real goal.l

Comment: I want to ensure that my application is not leaking. (currently, tomcat detects "leaks" after stopping my application, and according to my heap analyzer this is caused that weak references are still being held)

Comment: Memory leaks are only a problem if you run out of memory. If you don't, having even a real memory leak is completely uninteresting. And since weak links won't lead to OOM exceptions anyhow - why bother?

Comment: All weak references should be cleared with GC, if the referents are only weakly reachable. Are you confusing them with [soft references](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)?

Comment: @Voo:`Memory leaks are only a problem if you run out of memory`.Interesting thinking....I guess this is correct if your application is the only one running in the system....

Comment: @user384706 - and you're not running with any virtual memory where, even if you don't run out of memory, you might cause thrashing.

Comment: @RHSeeger Since you aren't actually accessing the data, not really a problem with thrashing, if you run out of memory those pages should just be written out to the swap file in a low priority process. Obviously that's all assuming you limit the amount of memory the JVM can use to something reasonable - after all the whole reason for using soft reference IS to use the available memory for caching something. If you want to limit the JVM to as less memory as possible - don't use weak refs. The usual space vs. time tradeoff.

Comment: @Voo - you're assuming none of your leaked memory shares pages with used memory. It's entirely possible for those leaked references to use up partial pages of memory and cause thrashing. And the sub-discussion was in relation to your blanket statement that memory leaks that don't lead to an OOM error don't matter, and reasons it might be untrue.

Answer (score 2):

SoftReferences are cleared when memory is low.

WeakReferences are cleared more often (like all the time when an object only has weak references left)

Check out the offcial Java doc for the package (the package documentation is useful to explain):
    http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html

Can you quote the exact message you are seeing from Tomcat on shutdown ?  are you sure you are not misinterpreting it ?  What is important for Tomcat is that there are no hard-references that are pinning the ClassLoader for the ServletContext.

Re WeakHashMap: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html
Only the keys are Weakly held.  What are you using as the "value" ?  does the value self-reference its own "key" strongly ?  With this I am questioning your understanding of what a WeakHashMap is providing for you (this presumes it is the correct tool for the job).

In my experience you can get the WeakReferences with Sun JVM 5 to be cleared with System.gc() 100% reliable for me on the first GC sweep.  But they don't guarantee that point.